# How to call GET method with URL and take HTML response in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, get, cors, flutter-web

My task is to call the link in web using flutter through the GET method and get the html which in the future I want to show on the same page where I am.

Here is an example:

```
final response = await http.get('SOME URL',
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print("200: Try to get HTML");
  // TODO get HTML from response
  return jsonDecode(response.body).toString();
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}
```

The problem is that when **I initialize the page, I call this link**, but the **browser blocks** and does not allow calling

Error example:

[image]

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://localhost:55827' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

As far as I could figure it out, the problem is that I call some other link on the localhost and because of this the CORS blocks.

I could not find a solution to this problem. Please help me how, during initialization, could I call the GET method with url and take html from the response ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow cross origin request in the backend page you are using, not in http header. The command if different depending on the language you are using i.e. php, node js, python etc. for your backend.

Like if you are using PHP then you have to specify this header -

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`